# wordpress get url of registered script

Tags: php, wordpress

If I register a script or style (using `wp_register_script()` or `wp_register_style()`), is there a way I can get the URL of that script/style?

*(If you must know why, I'm trying to put those URL's into another function that generates prefetch link tags so I can prefetch certain scripts/styles for a performance boost in my site.)*

Answer (score 3):

Just in case someone is still looking for this:

```php
<?php
function invdr_get_script_uri_by_handler( $handler ){
    //Get an instance of WP_Scripts or create new;
    $wp_scripts = wp_scripts(); 

    //Get the script by registered handler name
    $script = $wp_scripts->registered[ $handler ]; 

    if ( file_exists( ABSPATH . $script->src ) ){
        return ABSPATH . $script->src;
    }
    return false;
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'invdr_get_script_uri_by_handler', PHP_INT_MAX );
```

Tested in wordpress 5.0

Comment: Thank you for example but this part `file_exists( ABSPATH . $script->src )` always returns "true" such as if_exists checks for available files and !!!folders. If replace `file_exists` with [is_file](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.is-file.php) all work correct.

Comment: This returns the path to the resource, not the URL.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `wp_scripts()` to get the instance of the `WP_Scripts` class which contains the registered scripts (this class extends `WP_Dependencies`).

Basically, try looking in:

```
$wp_scripts = wp_scripts();
var_dump( $wp_scripts->registered );
var_dump( $wp_scripts );
```

Comment: I tried this and unfortunately nowhere in the returned data had the file name of my registered scripts/styles anywhere. :( I appreciate the answer, though.

Comment: I followed through the code to see how `wp_register_script` works and it lead me to that class, you'll find a reference to `$wp_scripts->add(` (tested under wordpress 4.8.3)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I've accomplished this in a self-authored plugin to help me enhance dependencies within WordPress:

```php
// Convert relative URL to absolute?
$absolute = true;

$handle = 'your_stylesheet_handle';
$helper = wp_styles();
$object = $helper->registered[ $handle ];
$src    = $object->src;

if (
    $absolute
    && $helper->in_default_dir( $src )
) {
    $src = $helper->base_url . $src;
}

$ver = $object->ver;

if ( ! is_null( $ver ) && empty( $ver ) ) {
    $ver = $helper->default_version;
}

if ( isset( $helper->args[ $handle ] ) ) {
    $ver = $ver ? $ver . '&#038;' : '';
    $ver .= $helper->args[ $handle ];
}

$src = add_query_arg( 'ver', $ver, $src );

$stylesheet_url = urldecode_deep( $src );
```

Note that the absolute URL conversion is directed towards handling assets registered by WordPress core, as they're typically relative URLs.